# How to get data from html form using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How I can pass/get data from the html form in Google apps script?
I was trying many times but still can't get the right code. I hope someone can help me here with this problem.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getValuesFromForm(form) {
    var firstname = form.lastname,
        lastname = form.firstname,
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1XvrQFzVTlCqtB6HGggeGKraaLrd_8wdw6rAGVNVxYC0');
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow([firstname, lastname]);
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<form>
  First name: <input id="firstname" name="firstName" type="text" />

  Last name: <input id="lastname" name="lastName" type="text" />

  <input onclick="google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(this.form)" type="button" value="Add Row" />
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the issue with the code you have posted in question ?

Comment: It saying undefined value when i execute it. I cant get the value of those textbox from the form to the function

Comment: How you're executing it ?

Comment: when i click the button in the form. the getValuesFromForm will call it. but not getting value from it

Comment: Ok, I have posted the answer. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: still not work sir :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things :

1. We have to pass parent , so that we can access it's children. this.form will send nothing[I guess] because this[input button] doesn't have form child. Rather you should send form[using parentNode or getElement()]
2. We have to use field `name` and not `id` [currently you are using id, cross check it, see capitalization]

So you have two options :

1. Change name of fields to match that in script

```html
<form id='myForm'>
    First name: <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" /> Last name: <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />
    <input onclick="google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.getElementById('myForm'))" type="button" value="Add Row" />
</form>
```

**OR**

2. Change name used in script to match that in form

use `form.firstName` and `form.lastName` in script in `code.gs` [instead of `form.firstname` and `form.lastname`]

Comment: still getting undefined value

Comment: Cool. I have updated the answer to help understanding the issue instead of only getting it solved.

Comment: ohhh. I see. thats why its getting null because of the name of the textboxes. my bad XD

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to change your form to use a "submit" type form and put the action in the main form field, as shown below:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(this)">
  First name: <input id="firstname" name="firstName" type="text" />

  Last name: <input id="lastname" name="lastName" type="text" />

  <input type="submit" value="Add Row" />
</form>
```

I believe the .gs code in  your original question will work unmodified with this form.